# How to connect registration form to database in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

How to connect registration form to database in WordPress
 Connect registration page in WordPress to MySQL databases?

Answer (score 0):

Create Your custom form and use `wp_insert_user` function for user registration.

```
<?php

$website = "http://example.com";
$userdata = array(
    'user_login'  =>  'login_name',
    'user_url'    =>  $website,
    'user_pass'   =>  $password,
);

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

//On success
if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    echo "User created : ". $user_id;
}

?>
```

To add a user use ether `wp_insert_user` or `wp_create_user`.   `wp_create_user` ONLY creates a user, and does not allow for managing any extra user fields. `wp_insert_user` allows for filling in all user fields.

```
<?php wp_insert_user( $userdata ); ?>
```

Comment: Check my website 99tripindia.com/register

Comment: And tell me how to connect with database

Comment: you have basic knowledge in php or not ? 
for registration. simple get all form data from post and add it on my query. 
and before that make sure that you have created extra fields for users.

Comment: Tlell me detailed procedure for WordPress

Comment: its not platform where i made full code for you.
 if you don't know basic then start with php.

 i already give you code details that how user will register on site. 

if you can try this code and make your custom form then user will register.